# Android - Linking and object to a Class Variable

Tags: java, android

I have an Object in the MainActivity used just there. I have a cuople of classes which could modify or use that object. My question is if I can link this object passing as a parameter to the constructor of the other classes. For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    Player myPlayer;
    MyClass myObject;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myObject = new MyClass(myPlayer);
    }
}
```

And within the class

```
public class MyClass {
    Player linkedPlayer;
    public MyClass(Player mainPlayer){
        linkedPlayer = mainPlayer;
    }
    public void playPlayer(){
        linkedPlayer.play();
    }
}
```

The real question is the if I do `linkedPlayer = mainPlayer;` the Player instance is cloned to the new var or may it be linked. If not linked, how is the method to link it?

My goal is to instantiate only one Player object and use it within the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you specifically write your own code to clone an object then assigning it to another variable will still be the same object.
You are effectively copy a (I hate the next word) POINTER to the object.

So, in your case, no you will not get a new copy. It will be the same one and any changes made in the second class will be visible in the first one.

Comment: That was my doubt, many thanks. I am really passing a POINTER of the original Player var. I was afraid I was not doing that. Thanks a lot!!!